# What is the Ubuntu command that allows you to specify what you will use the server for?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration

When you install an Ubuntu server, you get a screen to choose if it should have OpenSSH, be a LAMP server, have visualization, ...

There is some console command that shows you the same menu. What is it called?

I have just spent the last 30 min googling all kind of combination of install and setup and configure and command-line without success.

So, to recap, I made a wrong choice in the installation screen, and I want to correct it without installing from scratch, and so I need that command so I can remove that what I don't want to have installed. Since I haven't explicitly chosen any package, the usual package deinstall command will not help. And since it's a server, I need to know the *console* command to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `tasksel`.

Run it as root (via sudo).

Comment: ServerFault says @SvenW beat you by a minute. Sorry!

Comment: Useless noSQL - it showed me a 12 second lead on submission.

Comment: @adaptr Don't they use MSSQL?

Comment: @monster I think adaptr answered first, by 8 seconds. [See here.](http://serverfault.com/posts/386698/timeline)

Comment: Thank you @root45 I stand corrected. I didn't even know I could change the "selected answer", but that's a good thing in this case.

Answer (score 5):

`tasksel`, but all it does is some package-preselection, nothing you couldn't do with aptitude or something similar.

Comment: I swear when I saw you both that you were first, but the link that root45 showed me points to adaptr being in fact the first. Something like this never happened to me before. Either a glitch, or I somehow got it wrong. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. Both answers were correct, so I don't care which one you accept. I don't consider this a race ...

Comment: While you're leading by 15k, I do ;)